# Weird behavior for socket creation when implementing dynamic tcp-ip resolver using spring integration

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-integration, tcp

I've successfully implemented the dynamic tcp-ip resolver thanks to the dynamic ftp template in spring integration.

Everything works "fine". By fine I mean that my tcp/ip client can successfully connect to the target server:host and communicate data. After the tcp/ip channels been resolved, one message is sent through the outbound channel. When the first message is been sent, the tcp factory starts creating the socket connection. However, it seems that the socket creation using the TcpNetClientConnectionFactory is always taking 10 seconds the first time (my time-out is set to 45 secs).

```
2015-08-10 22:42:28.544 DEBUG 2607 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler    : org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler#0 received message: GenericMessage [xxx]
2015-08-10 22:42:28.544 DEBUG 2607 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory : Opening new socket connection to xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8005
2015-08-10 22:42:38.589 DEBUG 2607 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : New connection xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8005:36792:251ff706-12b8-44c5-94a1-8518b641a8e1
2015-08-10 22:42:38.590 DEBUG 2607 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8005:36792:251ff706-12b8-44c5-94a1-8518b641a8e1 Reading...
2015-08-10 22:42:38.590 DEBUG 2607 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler    : Got Connection xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8005:36792:251ff706-12b8-44c5-94a1-8518b641a8e1
2015-08-10 22:42:38.591  INFO 2607 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] ChannelSerializerDeserializerServiceImpl : Started serializing...
```

However, the message channels resolved after the first trail (another ip:port) take almost no time to establish socket connection. This is rather confusing to me. The new message channels resolved are in a new application context, different from the first one.

You can tell from the logs:

```
2015-08-10 22:42:38.771 DEBUG 2607 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler    : org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler#0 received message: GenericMessage [xxx]
2015-08-10 22:42:38.771 DEBUG 2607 --- [pool-2-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory : Opening new socket connection to xxx.xxxx.xxx:12602
2015-08-10 22:42:38.833 DEBUG 2607 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : New connection xxx.xxxx.xxx:12602:38520:ebd8e4ad-a749-48e4-bef0-79b68c6c49e7
2015-08-10 22:42:38.834 DEBUG 2607 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler    : Got Connection xxx.xxxx.xxx:12602:38520:ebd8e4ad-a749-48e4-bef0-79b68c6c49e7
```

I redid the experiment several times using several working environments and tcp/ip destinations. However, the tcp factory always takes around 10 seconds to get the first tcp/ip socket connection. Could someone tell me why?

---

Update: Okay, I was bored and tried to run for another time. Now it takes no time to get the first connection! I have changed nothing. I do not know what is related to this change.

---

Update2: It seems that it has nothing to do with the dynamic thingy.... Importing the xml file straight from the main application context still takes around 10 seconds to get the first connection...

```
MessageChannel messageChannel = (MessageChannel)applicationContext.getBean("toChatRoomTcpIpChannelCopy");
messageChannel.send(new GenericMessage<String>("some text"));
```

Comment: No op. Maybe some network glitch...